# How to store a specific named docker volume at a specific location without changing the default?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I would like to create a named volume for one of my containers.

This container will need a lot more storage than other containers I run, so I would like to store that particular volume on a different disk that has lots of free space.

I still want the other volumes on the default disk, only that one named volume should go on another disk.

I don't want to use a bind mount because it will make backing up and migrating more complicated.

The only option I can think of is to manually move the volume after it is created (while the container is stopped), and create a symlink from its original location in `/var/lib/docker/...` to the new location on the other hard drive. This is very manual though, which leads me to think there must be a better way.

What is the recommended way of achieving this?

Comment: https://github.com/projectatomic/docker-lvm-plugin might help, not sure how reliable it is

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the local volume driver:

```
docker volume create -d local -o type=none -o o=bind -o device=/host/path volname
```

(Taken from [this github comment](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/19990#issuecomment-248955005))

Comment: Does it make a `bind` type of mount, or a `volume` type of mount? Is it different than `docker run -v /host/path:/mypath ...`?

Comment: Technically, all volumes are bind mounts. This is a named volume using the local driver, which allows you to specify any mount type possible, including _bind mounts_

This seems like what you need since you want a named volume, but not a bind mount/host mount where you specify the host location on the -v argument.