# Rancher volume on Local File System

Tags: docker-volume, rancher

I'm using rancher with only one host for test. When deploying a container, I'd need to have access the container persistent data from the host, to simplify my test. One option I see would be that I mount a local filesystem path to the container as /srv/myfolder:/etc/myfolder. I've already done that with Docker.

I've tried to do it from Rancher, but it does work. Do I need to do something specific?

The second option would be to have a docker volume. I've tried, and it works. But I don't know how I could access it from the docker host. Is there a way to do it or is it not possible by default?

Thank you

Fabrice

Answer (score 2):

I think it is related to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47795951/1556857).

You can create a docker volume binded to local directory of your desire. Like this:

```
docker volume create -d local -o type=none -o o=bind \
    -o device=/srv/myfolder container_etc_volume
```

Then you can use it like:

```
docker run -d -v container_etc_volume:/etc/myfolder .....
```

Then you can access it from host:

```
ls -la /srv/myfolder
```